# Customer Name Formatter

Tags: c#, .net

I have a feature request to implement automatic capitalisation of the name fields.

- rachel mcMillan -> Rachel Mc'Millan
- dara obriain -> Dara O'Briain
- bill gates -> Bill Gates
- etc...

seemed like an innocent request before, no?

Unfortunately with such generic search terms, I'm struggling to find any help. If I have to implement this myself then I'd need a list of *"double"* last names (Mc' Mac' O' ... etc ...) or something to work from, but it occurs to me that this must of been done before.

So I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
D.R

Comment: A name is like a unique identifier, you're potentially changing who people are if you go ahead with this. You can never cover all cases and in fact just introduce a set of issues yet to come. Educate your client.

Comment: I think figuring out how to create O'Briain without creating O'Bama is what will make this project its own little never-ending nightmare.

Comment: John McCain says... Yeeehaaaaaa!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to approach this is to write a first approximation of a solution, i.e. turn everything into lowercase, capitalise first letters and handle extra cases you might think of.

Try going for an extensible solution and then just wait for **requirement changes**. It's the customer's job to provide you with the exact requirements. It will be their issue to differentiate the "O'Brian" and "Oblivious" cases.

Comment: Sounds good. Any program is correct when there is no specification of what is required.